# Vertex color display

Tags: texture-painting, color, vertex-colors

Blender v2.79 user over here. I've baked my texture to vertex colors and I was wondering: is there a way to view the RGB color of a selected vertex, much like you can see the XYZ coordinates of it in the side pannel ? I thought this would somehow be possible in paint mode, but I can't find it anywhere.

EDIT: an obvious way of doing this is to delete all vertices except the one I'm interested in, and then export an xyz-rgb .ply file for the model (which now contains only the one vertex). This, evidently, is incredibly tedious and I am asking for a faster way of retrieving RGB color for the selected vertex.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Gustavo

Comment: I can't find a way to do it, and even using the color sample eyedropper in vertex paint mode, I more often than not got a darker color than was there at vertex or even got the white of the selected vertex.